# Modify Object in Array with Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, nsdictionary

I have array:

```
var arrDicContact = udContact.valueForKey("arrDicContact") as [NSDictionary]
```

and i want to change one contact in array:

```
 for let dicx:NSDictionary in arrDicContact{
     if (dic.valueForKey("name") as String) == selectedName{
        //how to modify dic to newdic: dic = newdic
     }
 }
```

i can use for loop with int i from 0 to arrDicContact.count-1. But it's so not exited... i like for loop (for...in...) So anybody help me! :) Tks a lot.

Comment: you shouldnt modify a collection/array/list while iterating over it

Answer (score 19):

Assuming we have the array like this:

```
var array:[NSDictionary] = [["name":"foo"],["name":"bar"],["name":"baz"]]
```

Using `enumerate`

```
for (idx, dic) in enumerate(array) {
    if (dic["name"] as? String) == "bar" {
        array[idx] = ["name": "newBar"]
    }
}
```

Iterate over `indices`:

```
for idx in indices(array) {
    if (array[idx]["name"] as? String) == "bar" {
        array[idx] = ["name": "newBar"]
    }
}
```

More aggressively, replace whole `array` using `map`:

```
array = array.map { dic in
    if (dic["name"] as? String) == "bar" {
        return ["name": "newBar"]
    }
    return dic
}
```

Comment: I've voted for this answer; just a Swift 2.0 update - use enumeration like follows: for (idx, dic) in array.enumerate() {....

Comment: How should be if we have array with structures?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `NSMutableDictionary` instead, because you can't edit a `NSDictionary`.

Then you've got also a typo. In your if-clause you use `dic` but you need `dicx`.

After resolving that, in your if-clause you can do something like that:

```
if (dicx.valueForKey("name") as String) == selectedName{
  dicx.setValue(value: yourObject, forKey: yourKey)
}
```